# Is it possible to assign ATTRIBUTE values from an ARTIFACT in Enterprise architect?

Tags: scripting, enterprise-architect, artifact

I am trying to obtain Object Run State Values from a document.

I am trying to write a Diagram Script to parse Artifact content and assign them into Run State Values on the diagram.

How can accomplish these tasks?

Comment: What do you mean by "diagram script"?

Comment: Although the above comment is correct, don't get scared. I have an idea of what you mean. But you need to edit your question and clarify it.